# Connecting to a Windows XP network share from a Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking, vmware

Currently I have the following set up over a Belkin router:

- 1 machine running Windows XP Pro SP3 (XP)
- 1 machine running Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 (W7)

The XP machine has a network share on it that contains a shortcut to a program that I would like to run on the W7 machine. Both machines are a part of the same work group (WORKGROUP). The two machines are NOT seeing each other on the network however, both are responding to ping commands based off their IP address.

I enabled file sharing on the XP machine and made sure the Share name is less than the maximums of the Windows XP system.

Neither computer has each other listed in the Windows Explorer.

Both machines are connected via LAN cable directly to the router which provides access to the Internet for both of them. Both computers are able to connect to the Internet without fail.

What steps can I do to alleviate this?

Based on Kitet's response, I forgot to mention the Win7 machine has the Advanced Sharing Options as followings:

- Network Discovery is on, File/Print Sharing is on, Public Folder sharing is on, and password protecting sharing is OFF.

Comment: Can you connect from one to the other in Windows Explorer using `\\<ip_address>`?

Comment: I cannot connect using the IP Address either. Funny thing, I can access the web port of the second machine but typing in `\\192.168.2.2` yields me an error.

Comment: What is the error message. does it say "Access is denied" ?

Comment: Yes. It gives me the "Access is denied."

Answer (score 3):

You have to enable Win7 to see other machines, it is done by opening Network and Sharing Center (translated) then on the left pane there's Change Advanced Sharing Options (translated) and there are various options, of which "Enable network discovery" should be interesting to you, in this case.

On the other hand, I am experiencing some problems on my Win7 machine that is ocasionally unable to see any computer over the network, but when I type `\\computer_name` I can navigate to it.

Comment: I edited the previous question but I have attempted the '\\computer_name' method and didnt work.

Comment: You mention a router, how are these machines connected to it?

Comment: Edited above as well. :)